# Fix height definition for alert box

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to set the height for my alert box, I try as follow:

```
  @alert-box: 60px;

  .alert-msg {
    height: @alert-box;
    margin: 20px 0px;
  }
```

As result I've got
[image]

On the picture you can see, that the text on the second box is not in the middle of box. And html part

```
  <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1 portfolio-item">
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-msg" role="alert">
      <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</span>
    </div>
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-msg">
      <strong>Oh snap!</strong> <a href="#" class="alert-link">Change a few things up</a> and try submitting again.
    </div>
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-msg">
      <strong>Oh snap!</strong> <a href="#" class="alert-link">Change a few things up</a> and try submitting again.
    </div>
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-msg">
      <strong>Oh snap!</strong> <a href="#" class="alert-link">Change a few things up</a> and try submitting again.
    </div>
  </div>
```

How can I set the text in the middle of box?

Comment: None of them are technically in the middle--it's being positioned by the padding on the alert box.

Comment: Try with `vertical-align`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was not easy - http://jsfiddle.net/77p1pw39/1/

You'll have to add a `<span class="centered">` around the text.

```
<div class="alert">
    <span class="centered">text</span>
</div>
```

And the CSS look like this:

```
.alert {
    width: 300px;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    background: #ccc;
}
.alert:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: -5px;
}

.alert .centered {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0 10px 0 15px;
}
```

Credits to [Chris Coyier](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/), I'm very impressed by the technique, brilliant!